# script for restar button in unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

in my game after losing a level shows the restart button of the level . and the question is how to create a script that will show the restart button for example 3 times and after the fourth unsuccessful attempt will not show it anymore this is my script to call the button:

```html
  else 
         {
             yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.5f);
             GameUI.ShowRestartButton();
```

and this is the button script:

```html
 public GameObject log2;
     public void ShowRestartButton()
     {
         
         
         Destroy(log2.gameObject);
         Image2.SetActive(true);
         
 
     }
```

```html
public GameObject logC;
     private int deaths = 0;
     public void ContinueGame()
 
     {
         if (deaths < 3)
         {
             Destroy(logC.gameObject);
             deaths++;
             SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, LoadSceneMode.Single);
         }
             
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a counter, increment it after every level fail, and check if counter exceeded your maximum restarts.

Create counter: `int maxLoses = 3` `int currentLoses = 0`

```
currentLoses++; // increment the counter
if(currentLoses <= maxLoses) // check if you still want to show the button
{
    GameUI.ShowRestartButton();
}
else 
{
    currentLoses = 0; //reset your counter
}
```

Put this in your code responsible for losing, right after your yield statement:

Comment: I did something like this (3 script in question at the top). because I'm mainly talking about the continue game button, which after three failed attempts disappears and tells the player to restart the game, but it doesn't work and the button keeps showing up. Destroy LogC is that button

Comment: Probably loading scenes results in your death count being lost

Comment: how to avoid it